# Run Moodle as Web service

Tags: moodle

I would like to run Moodle platform as my API (Webservice) and build my GUI - Front end application (HTML5) as separate web application. Front end application integrates the API to perform all the operations.

How can I do it with Moodle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moodle does not work this way - there are some web service functions, that can be used for admin tasks, such as listing courses or enrolling users, but the vast majority of moodle only works when it controls the whole of the page being output.

Answer (score 0):

Moodle workflow is based on server side rendering and moodle doesn't work on your way. But if you want to try with your idea. I got have something for you.

1. Define API with AJAX base.
2. Creating page ex: products.php in your theme.
3. Fetch data in products.php from your API which you define in step 1.
4. Using mustache or html_writer to process data which you want to display.

Thanks. Hope it's help something to you.